# Workaround for url(#fragment) shadowTree bug in Safari?

Tags: svg, safari

In an SVG, `url(#fragment)` fails in Safari under some conditions when the ancestor SVG is in a shadowTree. This means filters and patterns in a custom element can just stop working sometimes.

Basically, when there are two instances of the SVG created from a template, and one instance is hidden, fragment references in the *other* instance stop working, e.g.

```
<template>
  <svg>
    ...
    <filter id="blur">
  ...
</>

...

(attach cloned template to new shadows etc... )

...


templateUsingInstance1.style.display = "none"

// And then the following doesn't work.

templateUsingInstance2.shadowRoot.querySelector("g").style.filter = "url(#blur)"
```

Full Example: https://jsfiddle.net/InBllm/dw4vhax0/2/

The bug has already been reported but I'm curious if anyone else has run into this and knows a work-around.

I've tried

- Inlining an SVG with relevant patterns/filters in the main doc and referring to that.
- Inlining another SVG in the shadow tree with relevant patterns/filters and referring to that.
- Referring to filters/patterns in an *external* SVG with relative and absolute paths. (Looks like this is a separate bug itself.)
- Changing the style attribute directly (opposed to in defs>style).
- Adding a base tag in the root HTML document.
- Create an extra instance from the template, hide it (without using `display:none`), keep it around forever. (If other instances are created and destroyed the problem comes back.)

Abandoning shadowDom avoids the issue but that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I got is this hack:

1. Create an extra instance from the template, hide it (without using `display:none`), keep it around forever.
2. Whenever an instance built from the offending template is removed, flash the stick-around instance. `el.style.display = "none"; setTimeout(()=>{ele.style.display = "initial"},0)`

This prevents breaking fragment references from getting stuck, but it can result in a one frame flash of missing filters/patterns...